# Should the supervisor work in the laboratory with the student during M.Sc.?

Tags: masters, supervision, lab-management

I was just employed in the foreign university as assistant professor. I am going to have one M.Sc. student soon but I am not sure how much independence should he get. At my previous university we needed to work with the M.Sc. students in the lab all the time as they were unable to do anything being alone in lab. How is it at your universities? Who teaches M.Sc. students the methods, presenting the rules in the lab etc.? (Food Technology.

---

The field is: Food Technology, generally lab work connected with chemical and physical methods like HPLC, spectrophotometer, rheology.

Comment: Food Technology, generally lab work connected with chemical and physical methods like HPLC, spectrophotometer, rheology.

Comment: If you don't show him how to work in the lab, are there other people who will? Lab technicians, PhD students, post docs? Is it their job to show him?

Comment: Having worked in different European countries I can tell you that would likely have to instruct the student basically from scratch. It is almost unbelievable how programs have sunk in a couple of decades. (IT, AT, FR).

Comment: So actually when you grade the thesis, so you assess your own job.